# Why is SERIAL and GENERATE ALWAYS AS IDENTITY asking for a user-provided value in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql-12

I tried using `SERIAL` and `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` but always got an error whenever attempting to insert into any table that use them.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE bar (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO foo
VALUES ('JOHN');
INSERT INTO bar
VALUES ('JANE');
```

I would get `invalid input syntax for type integer: "John"` when inserting into foo
and `invalid input syntax for type integer: "Jane"` when inserting into bar. As far as I know, it should automatically fill in "id" starting from 1 and only require "name" from the `INSERT INTO` statement.

Is there something I did wrong?

Comment: INSERT INTO bar(name)
VALUES ('JANE');

Comment: ^-- This or `INSERT INTO foo VALUES(DEFAULT, 'JOHN')`

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I forgot something like that...